# grep for PHP functions, while excluding class methods and pasted-in javascript

Tags: php, wordpress, function, grep

I'm grep'ping through WP core, attempting to write a grep statement that will find all PHP functions, while excluding any class methods or Javascript functions.

This is what I have now:

`grep -r --include=*.php 'function [A-Za-z_]\+(.\+)' .`

This is returning both polluted functions from class methods and JS functions.

Comment: Parsing the source using the PHP tokenizer is probably the more robust method...

Comment: @deceze thanks, I went with that solution, makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You might probably want to try http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/ I passed the entire WordPress code into PHPXref a couple of years back and was able to get the complete list of functions, classes etc.